# Android Studio Push Rejected

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to merge or rebase? I don't know what's the difference
I just want to push on github.

[image: push rejected]

Answer (score -1):

Click on a pull the branch first and resolve the merge conflict

Try again to push the code.

If there's any merge conflict it'll throw a message push failed. Nothing to worry about. It happens because of a merge conflict, Push the code again after resolving conflicts.